# How to run a shell script with the terminal closed, and stop the script at any time

Tags: shell, scripting

What I usually do is pause my script, run it in the background and then disown it like

```
./script
^Z
bg
disown
```

However, I would like to be able to cancel my script at any time. If I have a script that runs indefinitely, I would like to be able to cancel it after a few hours or a day or whenever I feel like cancelling it.

Comment: One way -- write its `PID` out to a file in a `/tmp` dir or say in a `/usr/local/run` dir. Then you can simply `kill $(</path/to/pidfile)` when you want to stop the process.

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit more please? How do I write the pid to a file? What would the path/to/pidfile be exactly? Do you have an example?

Comment: `./script && echo $! > /path/to/pidfile` The special variable `$!` holds the `PID` (*process ID*) of the last process started. So you save the `PID` to a file, then you can kill the process at any time by issuing `kill PID`. You can also use the `pidfile` to verify only one instance of `script` is running. You can add a `trap` to `script` to remove `/path/to/pidfile` on script termination. (there are many examples of each on StackOverflow)

Comment: I don't get the PID written to the file I direct it to. When I do `user@server:/directory> ./script.sh && echo $! > test_file.txt` There is no file called test_file.txt

Comment: You are using redirection. `echo stuff > file` will write `stuff` into `file` (replacing any previous contents). When you `echo $! > file` as the first command after starting `./script` it will write the contents of the special variable `$!` (containing the `PID` for processing running `./script`) into `file`. You can then `read thepid < file` or just `thepid=$(<file)` to read the PID into the variable `thepid` which you can use to `kill $thepid` (or just `kill $(<file)`)

Comment: Note: I think where there was some confusion was with backgrounding your process first. You simply need `./script &` (to background) followed by `echo $! > /path/to/pidfile`. Putting it altogether it is `/script & echo $! > /path/to/pidfile`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having a bit of trouble following along, let's see if we can keep it simple for you. (this presumes you can write to `/tmp`, change as required). Let's start your script in the background and create a `PID` file containing the `PID` of its process.

```
$ ./script & echo $! > /tmp/scriptPID
```

You can check the contents of `/tmp/scriptPID`

```
$ cat /tmp/scriptPID
######
```

Where `######` is the PID number of the running `./script` process. You can further confirm with `pidof script` (which will return the same `######`). You can use `ps aux | grep script` to view the number as well.

When you are ready to kill the `./script` process, you simply pass the number (e.g. `######`) to `kill`. You can do that directly with:

```
$ kill $(</tmp/scriptPID)
```

(or with the other methods listed in my comment)

You can add `rm /tmp/scriptPID` to remove the pid file after killing the process.

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.